# Error of layout xml : Element 'update': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, theme, xml

I'm upgrading a theme from 2.2.x to .2.3

there are so many xml in this theme have the following directive

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <update handle="sales_order_item_renderers"/>
        <update handle="sales_order_item_price"/>
        <update handle="sales_order_info_links"/>
        <body>
        .........
```

error message display when i visit on front page:

```
Element 'update': This element is not expected
```

If update element is not supported, how can i migrate these statements to supported version?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to follow this command :-**

> rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/
>   pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache
>   var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session
>   generated/code
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
>
> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

**And Give Proper Permission**